# Custom command and possibilty to import from many sources

Tags: python, django, import, command, arguments

I am working on import in django 1.8. I would like to have possibilty to import data from two sources - one and two.

If I put in command argument one (`python manage.py import_data one`) - I import data from one, and the same with two - two in command - from source two (`python manage.py import_data two`).

But for now, when I want to run `python manage.py import_data two` in handle I recived `one` instead of `two`.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('one', type=str, nargs='?', default='one')
        parser.add_argument('two', type=str, nargs='?', default='two')

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if options['one']:
            print('one')
            return
        if options['two']:
            print('two')
            return
```

Comment: You should probably run it like: `python manage.py import_data --two xyz`.  Curretnly the first argument passed is consider to be the `one` param` unless you name it. But actually, you should consider a single argument, e.g. `source`, and handle the 2 different values it can have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using argparse wrong. You have two separate arguments, each of which has a default - so if you don't supply `one`, it will be set to the default value of "one", which defeats the purpose.

Instead you should have a single argument, `source`, which can have values of "one" or "two":

```
parser.add_argument('source', type='str', nargs=1, choices=['one', 'two'])
```

Now you can do:

```
if options['source'] == 'one':
    ...
```